# Read file line by line in PowerShell taking a single string

Tags: powershell

I want to read a file line by line in PowerShell. Specifically, I want to take a value with the date "30-Jun-2020", however I only managed it with the entire line.

I know the command with get-content:

```
$GetData = (Get-Content .\file.dat -TotalCount 3)[-1]
```

But how do I get just a single value in the string?

```
SERVER SCTTP0012CLD 0050568E4146 7260
DAEMON server01.d D:\GCTI\LicenseManager1\server01.d.exe port=2345
FEATURE 3GP08590BCAA server01.d 8.0 30-jun-2020 18144 581E94E4546D \
vendor_info="v8.0 - server01 CIME Platform - MS" NOTICE="afric \
```

Comment: You could use regex or if the string you're after is always at the same position you could use string methods like `.substring()` or `-split`.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a regex (regular expression) with the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to extract a date in the form `dd-MMM-yyyy` from the line of interest:

```
(Get-Content .\file.dat -TotalCount 3)[-1] -replace '^.+?\b(\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{4})\b.+$', '$1'
```